# Detect selection of multiple column headers in Tableview

Tags: tableview, listener, javafx-8

I am trying to detect the selection of multiple column headers in a tableview.

However, the code inside the listener attached to the selected cells in the tableview never gets called when a column header of a tableview is selected.

The code selection below shows the source code of a complete small example application. It contains two ListChangeListeners. The first listener is attached to the ObservableList containing the data of the table. It gets called on every click on the header. The second listener is attached to the selected cells of the table. However, this listener never gets called when a tableview column header is selected.

```
    package TableViewHeaderListener;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;

    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
    import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
    import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
    import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
    import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

    import javafx.scene.Scene;

    import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
    import javafx.scene.control.TablePosition;
    import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
    import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellDataFeatures;
    import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import javafx.util.Callback;

    public class TableViewExample extends Application {

      final TableView<String[]> table = new TableView<String[]>();
      ObservableList<String []> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

      @Override
      public void start(Stage stage) {

        Pane pane = new Pane();

        String[][] dat = new String[][]{    {"C1","C2","C3"},
                {"1","1","0"},
                {"0","0","1"},
                {"1","1","1"}};


        data.addAll(Arrays.asList(dat));
        data.remove(0); 


        for (int i = 0; i <  dat[0].length; i++) {
             TableColumn tc = new  TableColumn(dat[0][i]);
             final int colNo = i;

            //Adds data to table and calls updateItem, which also colors heatmap 
            tc.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<String[], String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
                public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<String[], String> p) {
                     return new SimpleStringProperty((p.getValue()[colNo]));
                 }  
             });

             table.getColumns().add(tc); 
          }


        table.setItems(data); 
        table.setVisible(false);
        table.setVisible(true);

        pane.getChildren().add(table);


        data.addListener(new ListChangeListener<String []>() {
          @Override
          public void onChanged(Change change) {
              System.out.println("data: ListChangeListener");
              //This prints when a column header is clicked
          }     
        });

        table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        ObservableList<TablePosition> selectedCells = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells();
        selectedCells.addListener(new ListChangeListener<TablePosition>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Change change) {
            List<Integer> selectedRowIndices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    List<Integer> selectedColumnIndices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    try{ 
                selectedRowIndices.clear();
                selectedColumnIndices.clear();

                   for (TablePosition pos : selectedCells) {
                    selectedRowIndices.add(pos.getRow());
                    selectedColumnIndices.add(pos.getColumn());
                   }
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.err.println(e.getMessage()+e.getCause());
            }
            System.out.println("ListChangeListener<TablePosition>: selectedRows: "+selectedRowIndices+"selectedColumns "+selectedColumnIndices);
            //This never prints even when a column header is selected or deselected
          }
       });

        stage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
        stage.show();
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hmm... your example behaves as I would expect: clicking the header doesn't change the selection as such, it only sorts: if there are selected cells, they are re-ordered - and with them the selection - and both listeners are called.

Comment: But how can I then detect the selected headers in the TableView ? I

Comment: headers are not selected (at least not in win7, could be different in linux/mac) - what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I would like to select multiple column headers and then use a button to mark them in a different color. I already solved how change the color of a given selection of  headers but I did not find a way how to detect which headers are selected.

Comment: There is no built-in functionality for selection of columns: e.g. there is no selection model associated with the table view's columns list. You would have to implement this yourself, i.e. register mouse listeners with the column headers and manipulate the list of selected table cells (or whatever it is you want to do) in response.

Comment: Thank you. I was not sure if I just overlooked something or if this functionality doesn't exist.